# Opening <script> tag "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'"

Tags: javascript

I am doing practice problems with loops and every time I try to run this in the console I get "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'". It happens on the opening  tag. Does anyone know what the problem is?

```
<script>
    const name = 'Mustafa';
    const para = document.createElement('p');

    const phonebook = [
      { name : 'Chris', number : '1549' },
      { name : 'Li Kang', number : '9634' },
      { name : 'Anne', number : '9065' },
      { name : 'Francesca', number : '3001' },
      { name : 'Mustafa', number : '6888' },
      { name : 'Tina', number : '4312' },
      { name : 'Bert', number : '7780' },
      { name : 'Jada', number : '2282' },
    ]

    for (let i = 0; i < phonebook.length; i++) {
        if (name === phonebook[i].name) {
            para.textContent += `${phonebook[i].name} ${phonebook[i].number}`;
        }
    }

    // Don't edit the code below here!
    const section = document.querySelector('section');
    section.appendChild(para);
  </script>
```

There is an open and close script tag so I expected it to work fine.

Answer (score 3):

The Console provides you with a JavaScript REPL. It expects you to enter JavaScript, only JavaScript, and nothing but JavaScript at the prompt.

`<script>` and `</script>` are HTML, not JavaScript.